# How to get Re-Captcha Values in LIFERAY

Tags: liferay, liferay-6, captcha, recaptcha

How can I get the Captcha value in Liferay.

To check the value I call check() from CaptchaUtil

```
 CaptchaUtil.check(actionRequest);
```

But I didn't find how to get the captcha Value.

I'm Using LIFERAY 6.2 EE

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Try to get it from a portlet session:

```
String captchaText = (String) actionRequest.getPortletSession().getAttribute(WebKeys.CAPTCHA_TEXT);
```

Comment: @wikimix It exists but normally you have no access to it. Those WebKeysa are only available to portal internal implementation classes (see https://github.com/liferay/liferay-portal/blob/6.2.x/portal-impl/src/com/liferay/portal/util/WebKeys.java#L62).

However you could just use captcha attribute name directly:

     `String captchaText = (String) actionRequest.getPortletSession().getAttribute("CAPTCHA_TEXT");`